# How to get the line number of image where alt/title is missing..?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm using a javascript function that uses regular expressions to get a list of images without an alt/title attribute:

```
function AltTitle(aSourceHTML, aResultField) {
  try {
  regexp = /<img((?:(?!alt)[^<>])*)>/gim;
      var vArray = aSourceHTML.match(regexp);
      var vLinks = vArray.join("\n\n");
      aResultField.value = vLinks;
  } catch (err) {
      alert("No Images Found");
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get the line numbers along with the image list?

Comment: Do you mean line number in the HTML file? Also I'd highly recommend using something like jQuery's filter function to collect and process your image tags.

Comment: What is the purpose of identifying the line numbers?

Comment: @elclanrs To find them in the source and correct them, perhaps?

Comment: I'd use http://validator.w3.org/ for that, unless OP is actually trying to build something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DOM instead to grab the images.

```
var imgs = [].filter.call(document.images, function(img) {
  return !img.alt && !img.title;
});
```

This will grab all images that don't have `alt` or `title` attribute or is empty, but it won't tell you what line the image is at. Try using http://validator.w3.org/ to find that out.

Comment: How, pray tell, does this retrieve the line numbers of the images?

Comment: Oh, didn't catch that part at the end. No it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "The Pony He Comes", but this seems to be more dealing with the plain text than the actual HTML.

The way I would do this is to first just split the whole thing on newlines, then loop through each line and run your regex against it. Since you're iterating through the lines, just print out the current iterator value and there you have your line number.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the source code in a variable, you can split it up by line breaks, and then run your regex against each line.

```
function AltTitle(aSourceHTML, aResultField) {
    aSourceHTML = aSourceHTML.split('\n');

    for (var i = 0; i < aSourceHTML.length; i++ {
        // run your regex against aSourceHTML[i]...
    }
}
```

If you are trying to do this for a specific page, such as the one you are on, you can do an ajax request for it, and then split that by line breaks and run through it. Try running the following code right here on Stack Overflow in a console. It will show the HTML of this page, with line numbers.

```
$.get(window.location, function(data){
    data = data.split('\n');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log('line ' + i, data[i]);
    }
});
```

But unless you're trying to write a tool for this in javascript, you should just use http://validator.w3.org/. It will find any images without alts/titles for you.

Edit: Wrote an example of how this could work on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8X4K/

Comment: i tried with the following code.... But still not getting the output..
'
    function Alttitle(aSourceHTML, aResultField) {
        aSourceHTML = aSourceHTML.split('\n');
        regexp = /<img((?:(?!alt)[^<>])*)>/gim;
        for (var i = 0; i < aSourceHTML.length; i++) {
            var vArray = aSourceHTML[i].match(regexp);
          aResultField.value = "line no:"+ i +"\n" + vArray;
        }
    }'

Comment: @chethan I've modified your function and put it up on jsfiddle to show you how it could work. http://jsfiddle.net/c8X4K/